# c++ overloading =operator, RAII

Tags: c++

I'm trying to do a simple buffer and follow the RAII idiom

in main.cpp

```
int main()
{
    buffer buf(5);
    buffer test(10);
    test = buf;


    return 0;
}
```

in buffer.cpp

```
#include "buffer.h"
#include <iostream>
size_t buffer::get_size() const
{
    return length;
}
buffer::buffer(size_t length) : start(new int[length]), length(length)
{
    std::cout << length << +" size" << std::endl;
}

buffer::buffer(const buffer& rhs) : start(new int[rhs.get_size()]), length(rhs.get_size())
{
    std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), start);
}

buffer& buffer::operator=(const buffer& rhs)
{
    buffer temp = rhs;
    std::swap(*this, temp);

    return *this;

}

int* buffer::begin()
{
    return start;
}

int* buffer::end()
{
    return start + length;
}

const int* buffer::begin() const
{
    return start;
}

const int* buffer::end() const
{
    return start + length;
}
buffer::buffer(buffer&& rhs) noexcept
{
    *this = std::move(rhs);
}
buffer& buffer::operator=(buffer&& rhs) noexcept
{
    if (this != &rhs) { // if this is not the rhs object
        start = rhs.start;
        length = rhs.length;
        rhs.start = nullptr;
        rhs.length = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}
buffer::~buffer()
{
    delete[] start;
}
```

in buffer.h

```
#pragma once
class buffer {
    size_t length;
    int* start;

public:
    size_t get_size() const;
    explicit buffer(size_t size);
    buffer(const buffer& rhs);
    buffer& operator=(const buffer& rhs); 
    buffer& operator=(buffer&& rhs) noexcept;
    buffer(buffer&& rhs) noexcept;
    int* begin(); 
    int* end();
    const int* begin() const;
    const int* end() const;
    ~buffer();
};
```

Now as you notice in main buf is a smaller size than test. My question is what happens to the memory allocated by test on the line above test=buf?

Does it ever get cleaned up? Or do main have to finish before it gets cleaned up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the copy-and-swap idiom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom)  And https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading

Comment: Did you actually write this code?  If so, you should know what your copy assignment operator does.

Comment: @NathanOliver-ReinstateMonica I did but the copy assignment operator does not seem to remove the memory allocated by test when the copy assignment operator goes out of scope.

Comment: BTW, your copy constructor is invalid, you use `length` before it's initialized: `start(new int[length]), length(rhs.get_size())` (class members are always initialized in order of declaration in class, and `start` is declared before `lnegth`)

Comment: @FredLarson ops forgot to include the deconstructor fixed that now

Comment: @Yksisarvinen do you mean in the header file? so the header file should be  size_t length;
 int* start;

Comment: Or initialize `start` using the length from `rhs`: `start(new int[rhs.length])`. It's going to be less error prone than ordering members correctly.

Comment: @kino92 -- You need to have a working, non-buggy, copy constructor and destructor before utilizing copy / swap in the assignment operator.  Obviously this was not the case.

Comment: You can get rid of the resource leak in the move-assignment operator, by applying a solution I first came to know in [Arthur O'Dwyer's CppCon 2019 talk](https://youtu.be/7Qgd9B1KuMQ?t=2145): Instead of implementing both a copy-assignment and move-assignment, just supply `buffer& buffer::operator=(buffer rhs)` (note the pass-by-value semantics). This allows you to apply the copy-and-swap idiom without checking for self-assignment. And it solves another problem, too (watch the whole video to find out, which problem that is).

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I would avoid initializing start *or* length in the copy constructor.  Instead, delegate to the non copy:  `:buffer(rhs.legnth) { std::copy(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), start); }`

Answer (score 1):

The original array allocated by `test` will be swapped to the `temp` object in the copy assignment, and freed when that object goes out of scope.

But the move assignment has a memory leak, you have to free the old array before acquiring the new one from `rhs`.

And generally, I would recommend using `unique_ptr` instead of manual allocation.